# jQuery: Does not select correct dropdown value on page load

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm writing jQuery code for selecting select box value, on page load.

What I'm doing is:

- pulling value from db and storing in hidden input field
- get hidden field value in jquery
- have an if condition, which will decide which value to select

I'm using this jquery code to select value:

```
jQuery('#days option[value=Mu]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

It adds `selected='selected'` attribute to correct value but select box is showing default value.

I have no idea, what could be issue? Please help!

PS: If I run same code via console, it works fine. Maybe there's something causing conflict, but there's a lot of code so very difficult to debug without any idea.

**Edit:**

There are additional form fields, which are displayed based on selected value. The code is something like this:

```
jQuery('#days').change(displayFields());

function displayFields(){

var value = jQuery('#days option:selected').val();

 switch(value){
   case 'Mu':
      jQuery('#mondayFields').show('slow');
      break;
   case 'Tu':
      jQuery('#tuesdayFields').show('slow');
      break;
   default:
      break;
 }

}
```

If I remove this code, then it displays correct selected value. Which means, there's some conflict with this code.
BTW, it does not display correct dropdown value but it shows it's fields.

Comment: Make sure that your jquery code should be at the bottom once every element is ready/rendered. Or perhaps you can add more detailed code.

Comment: @imprezzeb I've found problematic function and added that code along with more detail.

Comment: please see my answer below. You need to use callback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on input provided it might be an issue of loading of the select element

Maybe

```
jQuery('#days option[value=Mu]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

executed before select element was loaded.

1. If so you can try above code in document ready something like this

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   ```
   jQuery('#days option[value=Mu]').attr('selected', 'selected');
   ```

   });
2. Try moving all your js code below HTML

**Based on EDIT made in question**

The code added in EDIT part should not affect select value so something else is wrong.

You can add a jsfiddle to help

Comment: if there's any issue of code placement, then it doesn't add `selected='selected'` attribute to the selected value. So it is clear that the code is executing. Secondly, if I remove the second code (function which triggers on value change) it works absolutely fine. So what could we assume?

Answer (score 0):

Use callback instead of calling the function: Please see below for the updated example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hiddenFieldValue = $('#hiddenFieldId').val();
    //here no need to add the selected attribute, just set the value.
    $('#days').val(hiddenFieldValue);       

    $('#days').change(function() {
        //here just get the select box id to get value. This will get the selected option value automatically.
        var value = $('#days').val();   

        switch(value){
          case 'Mu':
            $('#mondayFields').show('slow');
            break;
          case 'Tu':
            $('#tuesdayFields').show('slow');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    });     

});
```

JavaScript is async, so your previous is code does not guarantee that the function will be known during calling in your change method.

BTW: You can use $ instead of jQuery.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what about page load? this code won;t execute on page load. Additionally, it would be better if you can explain; why call back is required instead of function?

Comment: I've tried to use callback `.change` and `.on('change', function)` as well but still not working. :(

Comment: thanks for the edit, it works like my first code. It displays fields but does not show correct value in select box. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you change a value via jQuery you bypass the event trigger, you'll need to trigger it in code after you set the `selected` attribute.

Also leave the parenthesis off of the change event handler registration `displayFields` not `displayFields()`

```js
//doc ready
$(function(){
//to pass a function as a callback paramenter leave out the parentesis "()"
//jQuery('#days').change(displayFields());

  $('#days').change(displayFields);

  var option = jQuery('#days option[value=Mu]');
  option.attr('selected', 'selected');
  option.trigger('change');
});

function displayFields(){

    var value = $('#days').val();

    switch(value){
      case 'Mu':
        jQuery('#mondayFields').show('slow');
        break;
      case 'Tu':
        jQuery('#tuesdayFields').show('slow');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Days</p>
  <select id="days">
  <option value="">Empty</option>
  <option value="Mu">Mu</option>
  <option value="Tu">Tu</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="mondayFields" style="display:none;">
MONDAY
</div>
<div id="tuesdayFields" style="display:none;">
TUESDAY
</div>
```